# how to create custom capabilities for custom user role

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I have create a new user role.

```
add_role('lln_assessor', 'LLN Assessor', array(
'read' => true, 
));
```

this role will access a custom admin menu page .

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {

    global $user_ID;

    if ( current_user_can( 'lln_assessor' ) ) {
        add_menu_page('Axcelerate LLN','LLN Datas','read_assess_lln', 'Axcelerate_Link_Admin_lln_data','axcelerate_link_admin_lln_data_fn','','1.0' );
    }
}
```

but first I must create a custom capability for it.

```
$role_object = get_role( 'lln_assessor' );

// add $cap capability to this role object
$role_object->add_cap( 'read_assess_lln');
```

but the issue when I try to access the 'LLN Datas' menu in the admin dashboard I got this error.

`You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.`

I think the error was on the custom capability but I have no idea on how to fix it. please help.

Comment: use this plugin for capability https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the current_user_can from **lln_assessor** to **read_assess_lln**

```
if ( current_user_can( 'read_assess_lln' ) ) {
        add_menu_page('Axcelerate LLN','LLN Datas','read_assess_lln', 'Axcelerate_Link_Admin_lln_data','axcelerate_link_admin_lln_data_fn','','1.0' );
    }
```

And make sure you are logged in as lln_assessor instead of admin.